# Why does company autocomplete 1000 to "and"?

Tags: completion, company-mode, elpy

When writing python code in Emacs (GNU Emacs 25.1.1 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), I use company for auto completion.
Why does company autocomplete (some) numbers to keywords?

[image: Autocomplete 1000 to and]

Edit:
I used M-x company-diag and it tells me:

```
Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2017-09-15 on trouble
Company 0.9.4

company-backends: (elpy-company-backend elpy-company-backend elpy-company-backend company-bbdb company-nxml company-css company-eclim company-clang         company-xcode company-cmake company-files (company-dabbrev-code company-gtags company-etags company-keywords)
                  company-oddmuse company-dabbrev)

Used backend: elpy-company-backend
Major mode: python-mode
Prefix: #("1000" 0 4
  (fontified t))

Completions:
  "and" "keyword"
  "if" "keyword"
  "in" "keyword"
  "is" "keyword"
  "not" "keyword"
  "or" "keyword"
```

This looks rather odd to me. I can't imagine that this is a *feature* of elpy-company-backend...?

Comment: Depends on the backend, I suppose.

Comment: Please have a look to https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/1085#issuecomment-382910191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an old bug. It has been resolved with this patch:
https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/pull/1279